# Can't get the author's picture printed onto a node in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, variables, drupal-7, image

After reading the documentation, it seems that the correct way of doing that is like this:

```
<?php print $user_picture; ?>
```

Wich won´t work (it doesn´t print anything at all).

After asking around, I get this answer, which sadly won't work either:

```
<?php global $user;
$image = theme('user_picture', $user);
print $image;?>
```

That code was suggested as a "last resource", but when I try to use it, I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /includes/theme.inc on line 1054

Looking for that particular line: if `(isset($variables['#theme']) || isset($variables['#theme_wrappers'])) {`, and in context:

```
  if (isset($variables['#theme']) || isset($variables['#theme_wrappers'])) {
    $element = $variables;
    $variables = array();
    if (isset($info['variables'])) {
      foreach (array_keys($info['variables']) as $name) {
        if (isset($element["#$name"])) {
          $variables[$name] = $element["#$name"];
        }
      }
    }
```

It's [pretty clear](http://drupal.org/node/254940#user-picture) that it should work, but it doesn't.

Using contemplate module, I get this output as an alternative:

```
<?php print $node->picture ?>
```

Which won't work either.

I've tried then with Devel module (using the /devel tab of the node):

I get this:

```
picture (String, 4 characters ) 2876
$...->picture
```

Which won't work, because the output is just "2876", but is the only "picture" there.

So what can I do? How can I trace this problem?

Comment: -1 without any comment or explanation?

Comment: +1, seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that

```
theme('user_picture', $vars);
```

is a tpl.php file.
you can dpm($vars) of a preprocess function for this theme function and see what you can use.

Answer (score 0):

As per [node.tpl.php topic](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) in Drupal docs, $user_picture is a valid variable in node.tpl.php file (and its variations like node--book.tpl.php)

This code is wrong:

```
<?php global $user;
$image = theme('user_picture', $user);
print $image;?>
```

it's about displaying picture of current user, and it's not for Drupal 7 AFAIK.
Try dsm($content) or dsm($node) in node.tpl.phptofind the correct variable if $user_picture is still not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I´ve have the output of dsm($content) (because dsm($node) results in nothing in my case) here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/69/issuej.jpg/